# Basic Weather app: I'm trying to change what is displayed to the user based on what city they select on a dropdown

Tags: javascript

Currenctly I have the following dropdown:

```
<select id="dropdown">
   <option value="manchester" id="manchester" >Manchester</option>
   <option value="leeds" id="leeds">Leeds</option>
   <option value="london" id="london">London</option>
 </select>
```

I want the the selection of this dropdown to display the weather for that area. I currently have the following JS.

```
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(checked);

  var manchester = document.getElementById("manchester").value;
  var leeds = document.getElementById("leeds").value;
  var london = document.getElementById("london").value;

function checked() {
    if (document.getElementById('dropdown').value == manchester) {
      var lat = 53.48;
      var long = -2.24;
      weather(lat, long);
    } else if (document.getElementById('dropdown').value == leeds) {
      var lat = 53.80;
      var long = -1.5491;
      weather(lat, long);
    } else if (document.getElementById('dropdown').value == london) {
      var lat = 51.5074;
      var long = -0.12;
      weather(lat, long);     
   }
  }
```

This works, only if I manually change the html of each option to selected="selected". But I really want it to work upon the user selecting the option. It seems when you choose an option, it isn't automatically recognized as selected?

Would really appreciate some help with this and if possible, an explanation of how your code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you could say :

```
document.getElementById("dropdown").addEventListener("change",checked)

function checked(e) {
let  elm = e.srcElement //this just returns the element which has been changed (the dropdown) 
if (elm.value == "manchester") {
  var lat = 53.48;
  var long = -2.24;
  weather(lat, long);
} else if (elm.value == "leeds") {
  var lat = 53.80;
  var long = -1.5491;
  weather(lat, long);
} else if (elm.value == "london") {
  var lat = 51.5074;
  var long = -0.12;
  weather(lat, long);
```

}
  }

Answer (score 0):

you could add an event listener to get the value of the select tag with the onchange event and use that value to call the funtion that displays the weather